Is there a way to plot the geometric mean of antibody titres with 95% CI in a dataset with multiple groups?
I am trying to plot before and after geometric mean titres with 95% CI in a dataset with multiple groups.  My data looks like this:
id     d0     d28     group
1     1:20    1:640     A
2     1:320   1:320     B
3     1:40    1:2560    C
4     1:2560  1:5120    A
5     1:80    1:1250    B
6     0       1:320     C
I understand that to get the GMT, first I should do a log transformation. I found the following  in a post about geometric means:
gm_mean = function(x, na.rm=TRUE, zero.propagate = FALSE){
  if(any(x < 0, na.rm = TRUE)){
    return(NaN)
  }
  if(zero.propagate){
    if(any(x == 0, na.rm = TRUE)){
      return(0)
    }
    exp(mean(log(x), na.rm = na.rm))
  } else {
    exp(sum(log(x[x > 0]), na.rm=na.rm) / length(x))
  }
}

However, when I try to plot, I constantly get an "empty plot" and have not been able to include de d28 data. This is the code for my plot:
data %>%
  ggplot( aes(x=as.factor(group), y=gm_mean(d0)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE, alpha=0.6)+
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,1), breaks=c(1))+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))

Any ideas on how to do this?

gm_mean is a summarising function. Consider doing a summary on your data before plotting or simply use stat_summary in ggplot instead

https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/10/add-custom-summary-statistics-in-ggplot2/
